# How to refer to different templates in different apps in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

The structure of my project is this:

```
mysite/
manage.py
mysite/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
Home/
    templates/
        Home/
            Home.html
Login/
    templates/
        Login/
            Login.html
Application/
    templates/
        Application/
            Application.html
            Details.html
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('Home.urls', namespace="Home")),
    url(r'^Application', include('Application.urls',    
    namespace="Application")),
    url(r'^Login', include('Login.urls', namespace="Login")),
    url(r'^User', include('User.urls', namespace="User")), 
]
```

Home/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.Home, name = 'Home'),
]
```

Application/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'Application', views.Application, name = 'Application'),
]
```

The structure for the views.py(s) is the same for each app (with changes in names, of course).

Home/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

    def Login(request):
return render(request, 'Login/Login.html')
```

I have two links in my Home.html. One is supposed to direct a user to Application.html and the other, to Login.html. I tried to do the followings:

templates/Home/Home.html

```
<a href="{% url 'Application:Application' %} ">Apply Now!</a>
<a href="{% url 'Application' %} ">Apply Now!</a>
<a href="/Login/Login.html">Login</a>
```

None of them work. No errors, no redirections, nothing. 
**What is weird about this whole thing**  is that url changes for Login and Application look different, even though the structure of both apps are the same:

The url changes to:

http://localhost:8000/ApplicationApplication.html

vs

http://localhost:8000/Login/Login.html.

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

**mysite / urls.py**

```
url(r'^Application', include('Application.urls',    
    namespace="app")),
```

**Application/Application.urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'Application', views.Application, name = 'application'),
]
```

**home.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'app:application' %} ">Apply Now!</a>
```

Please change to retry